# updating mongodb gridfs file while keeping the id in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql, gridfs

I'm trying to update a gridfs file while keeping the original id. since there isn't really update in gridfsbucket I tried to delete and upload a new one but I can't change the id and would rather refrain from using the filename as id if at all possible.
I'm using the 2.10.2 c# driver.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you can Delete and Insert a new file, however, you can use the same ObjectId like the following

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");

var bucket = new GridFSBucket(database);
var objectId = new ObjectId();
await bucket.DeleteAsync(objectId);
await bucket.UploadFromBytesAsync(objectId, "file-name", new byte[] {1, 2, 3,});
```